# MasterDetailsView not updating on INotifyPropertyChanged events

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using a MasterDetailsView from the UWP Community Toolkit.
The data is hold by my [custom](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/Classes/CustomObservableCollection.cs) `ObservableCollection<T>`.
If I add or remove items from the list, an update gets triggerd and the `MasterDetailsView` shows the new list.

But if change a property of an [item](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/DataTemplates/ChatTemplate.cs) (e.g. chat, image, ...) of the list, the `MasterDetailsView` won't update to the new list.
It just triggers the `PropertyChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

It seams like the `MasterDetailsView` is not subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` events of the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Is there a way to get arround of this?

[=> Link to my implementation of the `MasterDetailsView` (.xaml)](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/Pages/ChatPage.xaml)

[=> Link to my implementation of the `MasterDetailsView` (.cs)](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/Pages/ChatPage.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set bind `Mode = OneWay` in binding

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind chatsList, Mode = OneWay}"
Chat="{x:Bind chat, Mode = OneWay}"
Client="{x:Bind client, Mode = OneWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is this, but if you change value of property inside item of list - observables can't "see" it. Collections can see when you are adding something or removing because this objects belongs to them and they don't have knowledge about implementation of stored items.

Try invoke PropertyChanged on changed item. I think it should work.

Comment: I'm already implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface [=>item](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/DataTemplates/ChatTemplate.cs) [=>ObservableCollection](https://github.com/COM8/UWP-XMPP-Client/blob/master/UWP%20XMPP%20Client/Classes/CustomObservableCollection.cs) and triggernig the `PropertyChanged` event.